# I can't get a push segue to work in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue

I'm very new, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Simplifying to the extreme, I have a `UIViewController` embedded in a  `UINavigationController`. The controller contains one `UIButton`.

This `UIButton` is connected to a second `UIViewController` by a push segue.

So when I press the button, it should segue to the second `UIViewController` and give me a back button to return, right? Nope.

Any suggestions?  I'm sure it's something obvious, but I'm baffled.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes.  Navigation controller --> View Controller -push-> View Controller

Comment: You should describe, step by step, what you did in the storyboard to set up your app. Also, if you've done anything in code, post that.

Comment: So @ClaytonGeipel by "silly mistake" does that mean you have found a solution? What was it?

Answer (score 1):

Start from scratch if you can and see if it works.

1. Make a new View Controller
2. Click to select the new View Controller, go to "Editor", then "Embed In", then selection a Navigation controller.
3. Place a UIButton on the first View Controller
4. Make a second View Controller
5. Control + drag the UIButton from the first view controller onto the second and select "Push" from the options

That should do it! Give it a go.